# Prove decimal number pattern for its n-bit 2's compliment

Tags: arithmetic, binary, number-systems

If we let $B =  b_{n−1}b_{n−2} · · · b_1b_0$ be an $n$-bit $2$’s complement integer.
How can we show that the decimal value of $B$ is $−b_{n−1}\cdot2^{n−1} + b_{n−2} \cdot 2^{n−2} + b_{n−3}\cdot 2^{n−3} + \cdots + b_1\cdot 2 + b_0$.

Comment: What definition of *2's complement* do you use?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by definition 2's complement?

Comment: You say that $B$ is an `an n-bit 2’s complement integer`. What do you mean by that? You must be using *some* definition of $2$'s complement since you ask about it. This matters because there are contexts where the $2$'s complement is *defined* by the expression you quote, in which case there is nothing to prove. So, I assume that you are using a different definition, but then you need to spell out which one.

Comment: The negative of a binary number represented by switching all ones to zeros and all zeros to ones and then adding one to the result. This should lead to 2 cases with the signed bit being negative or the signed bit being positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let $\;A=-B\;$ then, by the definition of $2$'s complement, $A$ is obtained from $B$ by flipping all bits and adding $1\,$:

$$
A = (1-b_{n-1})\cdot 2^{n-1} + (1-b_{n-2})\cdot 2^{n-2} + \cdots + (1-b_1) \cdot 2 + (1-b_0) + 1
$$

Let $B\,'$ be the given expression $B\,' = −b_{n−1}\cdot2^{n−1} + b_{n−2} \cdot 2^{n−2} + \cdots + b_1\cdot 2 + b_0\,$. Then:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
A + B\,' & = - 2 b_{n-1}\cdot 2^{n-1} + (2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}+\cdots+2+1) + 1 = \\
 & = -b_{n-1} \cdot 2^{n} + (2^n - \cancel{1}) + \cancel{1} \\
 & \equiv \;0 \pmod{2^n}
\end{align}
$$

Since $2$'s complement arithmetic is $\bmod 2^n\;$ it follows that $A+B\,'=0$ $\iff$ $B\,'=-A=B$.

Comment: @HassanArshad Edited for better clarity.

Comment: This is very late, but I'm not sure I follow your assertion that $A$ has the given value. What definition of decimal value are we using (when we're trying to prove a formula for decimal value in the first place)?

Comment: @1729_SR Not sure what you mean by "*formula for decimal value*". Decimal vs. binary are just different representations of the same value. For the $2$'s complement I am using the definition the OP posted in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132710/prove-decimal-number-pattern-for-its-n-bit-2s-compliment/2132736?noredirect=1#comment4385994_2132710) "*negative of a binary number represented by switching all ones to zeros and all zeros to ones and then adding one to the result*".

Comment: The very first formula you use, I'm not sure why that's general. Doesn't it assume that B is positive and so representable as $B = b_{n-1}\cdot 2^{n-1} + ... + b_0$?

Comment: @1729_SR Flipping the bits is a bit-level manipulation done on the binary representation of $B$, regardless of the sign semantics assigned to those bits. What is being proved is that $\,C_2(B) + F_2(B) \equiv 0 \pmod{2^n}\,$ where $\,C_2(B)=A\,$ is two's complement and $\,F_2(B)=B\,'\,$ is the binary expansion with the most significant bit negated.

Comment: Sorry that I missed this reply. I guess my confusion is that the line in which you write $A = (1-b_{n-1})\cdot 2^{n-1} + (1-b_{n-2})\cdot 2^{n-2} + \cdots + (1-b_1) \cdot 2 + (1-b_0) + 1$ seems to suggest that you are evaluating $B$ as $B = b_{n-1}\cdot 2^{n-1} + ... + b_0$, but that, a priori, is the evaluation for $B$ as an unsigned integer. Not sure if my question makes any sense, apologies.

Comment: @1729_SR There is only one way to evaluate a number written in positional notation. With a positive base, only positive numbers or zero can be represented, and negative numbers use a $"-"$ prefix. The way I read (and answered) OP's question is: *let $\,\overline{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}\dots a_1a_0}\,$ be an $n$-bit number in binary notation, and let $\,\overline{b_{n−1}b_{n−2} · · · b_1b_0}\,$ be its two’s complement, then prove that $\,-\,\overline{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}\dots a_1a_0} \equiv 
 −b_{n−1}\cdot2^{n−1} + b_{n−2} \cdot 2^{n−2} + b_{n−3}\cdot 2^{n−3} + \cdots + b_1\cdot 2 + b_0 \pmod{2^n}$*.

Comment: Sorry to keep perseverating on this but "if there is only one way to evaluate a number written in positional notation", then, in base-2 (positive base), how can (for example) 1001 ever represent a negative number? I must be missing something with definitions here, my apologies once again. Going back to your answer, it seems that we are saying that $B$ is a 2's complement number. OK. So it can be evaluated as $B = −b_{n−1}\cdot2^{n−1} + b_{n−2} \cdot 2^{n−2} + \cdots + b_1\cdot 2 + b_0\,$, but also as $B = b_{n−1}\cdot2^{n−1} + b_{n−2} \cdot 2^{n−2} + \cdots + b_1\cdot 2 + b_0\,$ (no - prefix)?

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this. Not sure why I'm struggling so much here.

Comment: @1729_SR "*how can (for example) 1001 ever represent a negative number*" $\;-\;$ Note that $\,−b_{n−1}\cdot2^{n−1} + b_{n−2} \cdot 2^{n−2} + \cdots + b_0 \equiv +b_{n−1}\cdot2^{n−1} + b_{n−2} \cdot 2^{n−2} + \cdots + b_0 \pmod{2^n}\,$ in all cases. The only difference is that the LHS has an integer range of $\,[-2^{n-1}, 2^{n-1}-1)\,$, while the RHS has an integer range of $\,[0, 2^{n}-1)\,$. Whether you (can) get negative numbers or not depends on the semantics you assign to the representation. But perhaps I misunderstand where the difficulty is.

Comment: In $4$-bit precision, for example, $\,p=\overline{1001}\,$ represents the residue class $\,2^3 + 2^0 \equiv 9 \bmod 16\,$. Its two's complement is $\,q=\overline{0110}+1$ $= 2^2 + 2^1 + 1$ $\equiv 7 \pmod{16}\,$, and it's always true that $\,p+q \equiv 0 \pmod{16}\,$. Then, how you map the residue classes to integers is a matter of choice. If you map $\,0\dots 15 \pmod{16} \mapsto {} 0\dots 15 \in \mathbb Z\,$ then you map $\,p \mapsto 1 \cdot 2^3 + 1 \cdot 2^0 = 9\,$, or if you map $\,\,0\dots15 \pmod{16} \mapsto -8\dots7 \in \mathbb Z\,$ then $\,p \mapsto -1 \cdot 2^3 + 1 \cdot 2^0 = -7\,$.